# Does the set $\{ (x,y,z) | x^2-y^2 = 0, 0 \le y < z \}$ determine a manifold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Does the set $\{  (x,y,z)  | x^2-y^2 = 0, 0 \le y < z \}$ determine a manifold?

From what I understand, the set looks like a triangle above the plane $xy$. However I can't present it in an implicit form.

I think it is a manifold since it doesn't include the $xy$ plane it self. However I don't know how to prove it.
I can't think of a proper parameterization.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visualizing - take a triangular sheet of paper and fold on an angle bisector. We have a vertex at the origin, a ray heading up from that, and two parts slanting up in the planes $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

Is it a manifold? Well, the most likely place for that to fail is the $z$-axis, and that's a crease. It's not smoothly embedded, but it is a 2-manifold.

Parametrization: $(x,|x|,|x|+t)$ for $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$, $t\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: So it is a manifold. Is showing this parametrization a sufficent proof? (since it's both injuctive and from an open set)

Comment: It's a full bijection, actually. If it wasn't surjective, we'd need other parametrizations to cover the parts of it that weren't included.

Comment: Yes I see. Thank you. Do you have another way to prove it is a manifold without using parameterization?

Comment: Not off the top of my head. The heuristic arguments that convinced me are the first two paragraphs. From there, unfolding the paper suggested coordinates, and that naturally led to the full parametrization. Once I had it, I stopped looking.